# Typescript for Sublime Text suddenly stopped working?

Tags: typescript, plugins, sublimetext

The Typescript plugin in Sublime Text (build 3126) stopped working for no apparent reason.

The problem is that it does not understand types anymore, thus the errors highlights and the autocompletions are disabled.

This happened on OS X 10.11.6.

This is the output in sublime text console:

```
2016-11-03 11:14:24,674: 140735275929600: WARNING: TypeScript plugin initialized.
plugins loaded
[rsub] Server running on localhost:52698...
lang_service_enabled: True
Path of tsserver.js: /Users/Arthur/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/TypeScript/tsserver/tsserver.js
Path of tsc.js: /Users/Arthur/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/TypeScript/tsserver/tsc.js
Trying to spawn node executable from: /usr/local/bin/node
ref view not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Arthur/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/TypeScript/typescript/listeners/idle.py", line 22, in _check_timeout_count
    self.handler()
  File "/Users/Arthur/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/TypeScript/typescript/listeners/idle.py", line 66, in on_idle
    self.request_errors(view, info, 500)
  File "/Users/Arthur/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/TypeScript/typescript/listeners/idle.py", line 105, in request_errors
    cli.service.request_get_err(error_delay, files)
  File "/Users/Arthur/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/TypeScript/typescript/libs/service_proxy.py", line 194, in request_get_err
    self.__comm.postCmd(json_str)
  File "/Users/Arthur/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/TypeScript/typescript/libs/node_client.py", line 143, in postCmd
    self.server_proc.stdin.flush()
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_plugin.py", line 818, in run_
    return self.run(edit)
  File "/Users/Arthur/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/TypeScript/typescript/commands/quick_info.py", line 23, in run
    cli.service.quick_info(self.view.file_name(), get_location_from_view(self.view), self.handle_quick_info)
  File "/Users/Arthur/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/TypeScript/typescript/libs/service_proxy.py", line 219, in quick_info
    req_dict["seq"]
  File "/Users/Arthur/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/TypeScript/typescript/libs/node_client.py", line 111, in sendCmdAsync
    if self.postCmd(cmd):
  File "/Users/Arthur/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/TypeScript/typescript/libs/node_client.py", line 143, in postCmd
    self.server_proc.stdin.flush()
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Arthur/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/TypeScript/typescript/listeners/idle.py", line 22, in _check_timeout_count
    self.handler()
  File "/Users/Arthur/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/TypeScript/typescript/listeners/idle.py", line 79, in on_selection_idle
    self.request_document_highlights(view, info)
  File "/Users/Arthur/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/TypeScript/typescript/listeners/idle.py", line 189, in request_document_highlights
    cli.service.async_document_highlights(view.file_name(), location, self.highlight_occurrences)
  File "/Users/Arthur/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/TypeScript/typescript/libs/service_proxy.py", line 259, in async_document_highlights
    self.__comm.sendCmdAsync(json_str, on_completed, req_dict["seq"])
  File "/Users/Arthur/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/TypeScript/typescript/libs/node_client.py", line 111, in sendCmdAsync
    if self.postCmd(cmd):
  File "/Users/Arthur/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/TypeScript/typescript/libs/node_client.py", line 143, in postCmd
    self.server_proc.stdin.flush()
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Package Control: Skipping automatic upgrade, last run at 2016-11-03 10:21:38, next run at 2016-11-03 11:21:38 or after
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed [this github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin/issues/452#issuecomment-200991425) and did as explained:

- download the gist, unzip it,
- replace the four files in [Plugin folder]/tsserver folder (to find it on OS X use `Sublime Text > Preferences > Browse Package...` menu and then navigate to `Typescript/tsserver`)

it worked.